# Fail Jenkins C# build if fortify scan results in new findings

Tags: c#, jenkins, fortify

How to fail, or mark build as unstable if fortify scanning reports new findings

Answer (score 0):

There is a Jenkins plugin provided by Fortify, currently available [here](https://marketplace.microfocus.com/fortify/content/fortify-on-premise-jenkins-plugin).

You configure its connection to SSC and it will upload a scan from your Jenkins workspace into an application version of your choosing.
The plugin then waits for some specified period of time in hope that SSC will finish processing that upload which is necessary to determine which issues are new compared to the last scan.

It doesn't poll SSC to see if the job is done unfortunately, it will always wait for the specified period of time in its configuration.

So, you should pick a time to wait that will allow SSC to process results in time, which will depend on load on your SSC server and the size of the FPR that needs processing. Ideally the plugin would wait just as long as necessary for SSC to complete the result processing, but not in the current version (18.10 at time of writing)

You can set a search criteria to run against the application version on SSC and if there's any matching vulns, your Jenkins build will be marked as unstable.

To mark the build unstable with any new vulnerabilities, use the search criteria: `[issue age]:new`

Comment: I have added fail condition [fortify priority order]:high category:Log Forging but it's not changing build status to 'unstable' even though there are High Category issues.

Comment: You mean to say in HPE Security Fortify Assesment Fail Condition?